# Handling Events For Controls Added At Run Time

Tags: wpf, vb.net, controls

I am adding controls at run time in a WPF App, these are all different types of control so are passed as a `UIElement`. I then get the `type` of control and can set the properties using `SetValue`. As I have a lot of control types to implement what I am now trying to do is is add an event to each control but can only seem to do this using `Addhandler` which requires a lot of extra code for each control as shown below. I am looking for a solution to allow me to add the error handler to the `UIElement` without prior conversion using a Cast, I am not sure this is possible?

```
 Select Case Control.GetType()
                Case GetType(ExtendedTextBox)
                    Dim newControl As ExtendedTextBox = TryCast(Control, ExtendedTextBox)
                    'Dim newCtl As UIElement = TryCast(Control, ExtendedTextBox)
                    If newControl IsNot Nothing Then
                        newControl.SetValue(ExtendedTextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                        newControl.SetValue(ExtendedControlProperties.HighlightTextOnFocusProperty, True)
                        newControl.SetValue(ExtendedControlProperties.MandatoryProperty, True)
                        AddHandler newControl.HasErrors, AddressOf UpdateErrorStatus
                    End If
```

Comment: You should have a look at DataTemplate. There is no need to do it like you do. See http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure how a DataTemplate would work in this scenario as I am adding multiple control types at run time, for example a textblock, a combobox, a button etc all of which I need the HasErrors event to be handled.

Comment: What is `ExtendedTextBox` and its `HasErrors` event? If it is part of a base class that the other controls also inherit from you can cast to that instead for those controls.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly prefixing my validation with "Customer." which as in inherited control was causing the issue, once removed it works as expected.